# wrapped C/C++ object of type Aplicacion has been deleted

Tags: python, interface, qt-designer, qmainwindow

I'm trying to run this code in Python but this error appears. Does somebody knows why? I'm trying to creat an interface using python and QtDesigner.

```
import sys
from Main_window import *
from Ventana_Dos import *
import conexion
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class Aplicacion(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.boton_ingresar.clicked.connect(self.iniciar_sesion)

        self.datos = conexion.Base_datos_usuarios()

    def iniciar_sesion(self):

        self.ui.contrasena_incorrecta.setText('')
        self.ui.usuario_incorrecto.setText('')
        Usuario_in = self.ui.usuario_in.text()
        Contraseña_in = self.ui.contrasena_in.text()

        dato1 = self.datos.busca_usuario(Usuario_in)
        dato2 = self.datos.busca_contraseña(Contraseña_in)

        if dato1 == [] and dato2 == []:
            self.ui.contrasena_incorrecta.setText('Contraseña Inconrrecta')
            self.ui.usuario_incorrecto.setText('Usuario Incorrecta')
        else:

            if dato1 == []:
                self.ui.usuario_incorrecto.setText('Usuario Incorrecta')
            else:
                dato1 = dato1[0][0]

            if dato2 == []:
                self.ui.contrasena_incorrecta.setText('Contraseña Inconrrecta')
            else:
                dato2 = dato2[0][1]

            if dato1 != [] and dato2 != []:
                for i in range(0,99):

                    self.hide()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = Aplicacion()
    app.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I search about this problem but I couldn´t find something. There are pages where peaople says that the problem is to repeat tn same 'QMainWindow' but i don´t have this line.

Comment: What is `conexion.Base_datos_usuarios()`? Please provide a proper [mre].

Comment: Base_datos_usuarios() is a data bases provided by SQlite

Comment: It's impossible to discover the source of the error without a proper [mre]. If you want help, provide more information.